# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se muestre una alerta si ya se selecciono ese producto?

Tags: html, angularjs

Quiero desplegar una alerta y que el botón de escoger no haga nada cuando un producto ya fue seleccionado.

Los productos se guardan en un array chosenProduct[] para que se muestren en una tabla más abajo.

El código JavaScript esta implementado con AngularJS y el código HTML esta con las directivas previamente declaradas en el script.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Las directivas de ng-show están declaradas según el atributo booleano de numPeopleShown; cuando este ultimo es false se muestra solo el botón choose, por otro lado si esta en true se despliegan un input number para añadir la cantidad que se requiere añadir.

```js
 (function() {
        var app = angular.module('AttractionsModule', []);

       
        var controller = app.controller('AttractionsController', ($scope , $window) => {
           $scope.quantity = null;
           $scope.show = null;
           $scope.productsChosen = [];
           


           $scope.attractions = [
               {id: 1, name: 'Uyuni Salt Flat', description: 'This is by far one of the most beautiful places on earth. Come to Bolivia and visit it', image: 'images/uyuni.webp', price: 3000, numPeopleShown: false},
               {id: 2, name: 'Tiwanaku', description: 'Located near La Paz city, it is undoubted one of the most outstanding cultural places in our country.', image: 'images/tiwanaku.jpg', price: 1000, numPeopleShown: false},
               {id: 3, name: 'Villa Tunari', description: "This is one of Cochabamba's most beautiful places. There will always be something to do here", image: 'images/villa_tunari.jpg', price: 2000, numPeopleShown: false},

           ]


            $scope.chooseAttraction = function (id)  { 
     
                attraction = _.find($scope.attractions, {id: id})
                attraction.numPeopleShown = true;


            }







            $scope.addAttraction = (id) => {
                attraction = _.find($scope.attractions, {id: id})
                let quantity = parseInt($scope.quantity);
                

                $scope.productsChosen.push({
                   image: attraction.image,
                    name: attraction.name,
                    description: attraction.description,
                    price: attraction.price,
                    quantity: attraction.quantity,
                    subtotal: attraction.price * attraction.quantity,

                    

                })

                attraction.numPeopleShown = false;

             

            }



            $scope.cancelAttraction = (id) => {
                attraction.numPeopleShown = false;

            }

            

            $scope.deleteAttraction = (id) => {
                var pos = $scope.productsChosen.indexOf(id);
                $scope.productsChosen.splice(pos);

            }


            $scope.view = {
                get total() {
                    return _.sumBy($scope.productsChosen, (ext) => {
                        return ext.subtotal;
                    })
                }

            }


        });

    }());
```

```html
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Practical Assignment 1</title>
            
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
          
            

        </head>


        <body ng-app="AttractionsModule">

            <div ng-controller="AttractionsController">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="banner text-white">
                        <div class="transparent p-3">
                            <div class="mt-4">
                                <h2>Tourist Attractions</h2>
                                <p>Everything you need to know at your full disposal</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="m-5">
                        <h3>Our attractions:</h3>
                        <p>
                            Have an amazing time when you come to Bolivia and choose among one of these attractions.
                            To add one of these attractions to your shopping cart just click on "Add to cart"!
                        </p>
        
                        <div id="attractionsCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#attractionsCarousel" ng-repeat="attraction in attractions" ng-class="{active: (attraction.id === 1)}" data-slide-to="{{attraction.id - 1}}"></li>
                            </ol>
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="carousel-item" ng-class="{active: (attraction.id === 1)}" ng-repeat="attraction in attractions">
                                    <img class="d-block w-100" ng-src="{{ attraction.image }}" />
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            <h5><b>{{ attraction.name }}</b></h5>
                                            <p>{{ attraction.description }}</p>
                                            <p>
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="!attraction.numPeopleShown" ng-click="chooseAttraction(attraction.id)">Choose!</button>
                                                <div ng-show="attraction.numPeopleShown  && ( attraction!=null">
                                                    <p>How many people with travel?</p>
                                                    <input type="number" min="1" ng-model="attraction.quantity" />
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addAttraction(attraction.id)">Add to Cart</button>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancelAttraction(attraction.id)">Cancel</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#attractionsCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#attractionsCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="m-5">
                        <h3>Your Shopping Cart:</h3>
                        <p>
                            Here are your choices!
                        </p>
                        <table class="table table-primary">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
        
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Product
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Price (Bs)
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        Quantity
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Subtotal
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="choice in productsChosen">
                                    <td id="image">
                                        <img ng-src="{{ choice.image }}" width="200" height="150" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h5><b>{{ choice.name }}</b></h5>
                                        <p>
                                            {{ choice.description }}
                                        </p>
                                        <div>
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteAttraction(choice.id)">Delete</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <b style="font-weight: bold;">
                                            {{ choice.price }}
                                        </b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <b style="font-weight: bold;">
                                            {{ choice.quantity }}
                                        </b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <b style="font-weight: bold;">
                                            {{ choice.subtotal }}
                                        </b>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <b>Totals:</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span><b>Bs. {{ view.total }}</b></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
        </body>





    </html>
```

Comment: Estas utilizando Angular o AngularJS

Comment: @2coolDevs
 AngularJS

Comment: Porque utilizas AngularJS si ya Google no le da soporte?

Comment: Es para una prática y se nos dijo que trabajemos enteramente con AngularJS